# Software updater - is there a way to change when exactly "display weekly" happens?

Tags: update-manager

[image]

Is there a way for me to specify exactly when "display weekly" means? E.g. I want the popup to show up at 9am Wednesday, or something like that.

Comment: Take a look at  the systemd unit files `apt-daily-upgrade.timer` and `apt-daily.timer`. There are time fields in the service files that may affect the scheduling you're seeing in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way specify times (or days) in the Software & Updates control panel.

Generally, it shouldn't be necessary for most folks: The displayed packages don't include time-sensitive security patches (your settings are to install those automatically right away). The only upgrades displayed will be non-time-sensitive bugfixes and backports.

- The actual Software Updater application is available from the terminal at any time: `update-manager`
- If you really want `update-manager` on a timer, you can use a cron job or a systemd timer. However, trying to run the application (which requires a $DISPLAY variable) that way might be more complex than is worthwhile for some users.